# Undeclared Identifier error for TwoSum C++ solution

Tags: c++, arrays

I am trying to create my own solution for TwoSum leetcode problem. I am assigning the array with random numbers in between 0, 20. I'm trying to write a function to find all
unique number pairs of the array that adds up to the
target number. Then I just want to print the pairs and their indices.

I am getting an undeclared error when I try to add the index of j to my array but I dont know why.

Here is my code, I appreciate any help or advice.

````
#include <iostream>
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
 
int getPairsCount(int arr[], int n, int sum)
{
  int indices[10];
     
    // Consider all possible pairs and check their sums
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        for (int j = i + 1; j < n; j++)
            if (arr[i] + arr[j] == sum)
                indices[0] = i;
                indices[1] = j; //error is caused by this line
 
    cout << indices;
}

int main()
{
   int sz = 20;
   
   int randArray[sz];
   for(int i=0;i<sz;i++)
      randArray[i]=rand()%20;  //Generate numbers between 0 to 20
  
  int n = sizeof(randArray) / sizeof(randArray[0]);
  int sum = 6;
   
    cout << "The indices that add up to the target sum is: " << endl;
    cout << getPairsCount(randArray, n, sum) << endl;    
    
    
    return 0;
 
}```
````

Comment: You need braces `{}` around multiple statements if you want them to be part of the loop. C++ doesn't care about indentation. `if (arr[i] + arr[j] == sum) { /* multiple statements here */ }` IMO you should always use braces for readability even for the outer loops that technically do not need them. It also helps to prevent bugs if more code is added later.

Comment: Thanks. After I added the braces the program keeps running ```0x7ffd89a14078The indices that add up to the target sum is:``` Do you know why?

Comment: Because `cout << indices` prints the value of a pointer to the first element, not the contents of the array. If you want that you need to do it manually.

Comment: The program causes undefined behaviour because there is no `return` statement in the function returning `int`

Answer (score 1):

Here is your code with some brackets:

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    for (int j = i + 1; j < n; j++)
    {
        if (arr[i] + arr[j] == sum)
        {
            indices[0] = i;
        }
    }
    indices[1] = j; //error is caused by this line
}
```

See the issue? You've indented `indices[1] = j;` which makes you think it's part of the "for j" loop, but it isn't. In older versions of the C++ this would have worked.

Comment: What older versions of C++ ?

Comment: Thanks. When I added the braces I got ```use of undeclared identifier 'j'```. Do you know why?

Comment: @M.M Not sure - just going of some Solaris compiler warnings from a recent port I was doing  that said the scope of j has changed.

Comment: @M.M Not sure if it was standard or not, but before Visual Studio 6 a variable declared in a for loop `for (int i...` could be used after the loop as well. We had to fix a lot of bad code when we switched. :)